# How to fix "NameError: global name 'ValidationError' is not defined"

Tags: mongodb, input, insert, validationerror

I'm working on this problem:

Insert new key-value pairs into documents using appropriate MongoDB statements. Specifically, create a function or method in Python or Java
that will read from a file or standard input stream a value pair stream in JSON notation and insert this document into the stocks collection. You
will also need to create a simple application scaffold for testing your function or method.

I've developed the code, and it will let me input information. However, it always leads to this error, and I don't know what is causing it.

```
import json
from bson import json_util
from pymongo import MongoClient

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['market']
collection = db['stocks']

def insert_document(document):
  checker = True
  try:
    stars = "*" * 50+"\n"
    print(stars)
    document = input('Enter Your Document: ')
    result = collection.insert_one(document)
    stars = "*" * 50+"\n"
    print ("\nSubmitted Document\n" + stars + document)

  except ValidationError as ve:
    abort(400, str(ve))
    checker = False
    stars = "*" * 50+"\n"
    return checker+stars

def main():
  myDocument = {"keyName": "test value data"}
  print insert_document(myDocument)
main()
```

Expected results:

```
*****************************************************
Enter Your Document: {"Ticker" : "123_EXAMPLE","Volume": 396,"Industry":"Example Industry Co."}
Submitted Document
*****************************************************
{"Ticker" : "123_EXAMPLE","Volume": 396,"Industry":"Example Industry Co."}
True
*****************************************************
```

Actual results:

```
**************************************************

Enter Your Document: {"Ticker" : "123_EXAMPLE","Volume": 396,"Industry":"Example Industry Co."}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 26, in main
    print insert_document(myDocument)
  File "test.py", line 19, in insert_document
    except ValidationError as ve:
NameError: global name 'ValidationError' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ValidationError message is because you have no reference to ValidationError in your imports. ValidationError is not an exception that pymongo will throw, so you could change it to a more generic

```
  except Exception as e:
```

The reason it is throwing an error is because you are trying to insert a string when you should be inserting JSON. Even though it looks like JSON, you must convert it to JSON using json.loads.

```
collection.insert_one(json.loads(document))
```